# In Excel, how can I use the LEFT function inside of an INDEX/MATCH?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

So my problem is this:

Sheet 1 has a pivot table, Sheet 2 has the comparable data and formula, which will feed into a GETPIVOTDATA formula.

Sheet 1 entities (row names) looks like this: `123456_ABC`

On Sheet 2 they look like this: `123456`

I'm trying to use an index/match function to get the full entity names from Sheet 1 without having to insert a new column:

```
=INDEX('Sheet 1'!A:A, MATCH('Sheet 2'!A12, LEFT('Sheet 1'!A:A, FIND("_", 'Sheet 1'!A:A&"_")-1),0)
```

I'm following this [guideline](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/13/excel-index-match-function-vlookup/):

```
=INDEX (column to return a value from, (MATCH (lookup value, column to lookup against, 0))
```

Its just not working. Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: For some reason, SO is not showing the _ in between " " after FIND

Comment: Did you try to test the functions individually? First check that `FIND("_", 'Sheet 1'!A:A&"_")` produces the expected result, then check that your `LEFT(...` works correctly, and so on. Also, post the result: what error message is displayed on the cell?

Comment: I don't have an Excel with me to check right now, byt are you sure about the `A:A&"_"` part inside your find function? `FIND("_", 'Sheet 1'!A:A&"_")`

Comment: As you doing string operations on whole column, it either won't work or will only work when entering formula in array type - once formula typed in instead of pressing enter, press ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: @mef Both functions work individually. I'm getting: #VALUE!   I'm pretty sure that the problem is with the nested LEFT function, since it refers to an entire column instead of a cell.

Comment: @Raugmor Thanks, that did it. Now to figure out how to get this working correctly nested inside of my GETPIVOTDATA function. Thanks again!

Comment: I was never good at remembering `GETPIVOTDATA`, try a trick i use: do a formula in one cell picking up the data from the pivot table you require, which will build up the formula in full and then manually change all the required arguments from constants to the variable you need.

Answer (score 0):

as requested by @pnuts

As you are doing string operations on whole column, it will only work when entering formula in array type - once formula typed in, instead of pressing `enter`, press `ctrl+shift+enter`